# Bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2

Tags: yii

```
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2', array(
       'asDropDownList' => false,
       'name' => 'clevertech',
       'options' => array(
            'tags' => array('clever','is', 'better', 'clevertech'),
            'placeholder' => 'disciplines',
            'width' => '40%',
            'tokenSeparators' => array(',', ' ')
       )
 ));
?>
```

Данный пример полностью с сайта yiibooster.clevertech.biz(офф документация) почему-то  вообще  не отображается на форме. Может подскажет кто , где можно подпилить что бы оное отображалось. (все настроено по инструкции  и другие компоненты прекрасно отображаются))

Comment: @Flur, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: дайте хоть демку того что вы делаете - явно же не правильно что то раз не работает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще я засовываю этот кусок кода в /layouts/main.php   и ничего не вижу на странице. Вообщем поигрался  с  'asDropDownList' => false,  если установить в true то  выпадающее поле отображается на  странице, но мне нужно установить его в false. Как  тута(http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/components.html#select2)